# How to unfold mesh with a principled BSDF material onto a flat object in 2.8?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to unwrap an image that I've applied to a mesh with a Principled BSDF shader. Here is the material node graph:

[image: shader editor view]

Is there a way to include the material I've applied to my icosphere in the UV unwrap?

Here is the UV map I want to unwrap to:

[image: UV editor view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add an image texture node
2. Click on new on it and create a picture file, this node must be active (select it)
3. Switch to Cycles render
4. Decrease the render sampling to 1
5. Select diffuse in the Bake tab and select only Color for the influence
6. Click on Bake then save the baked picture

[image]